# VIM loses syntax in current line

Tags: macos, vim

Why my current line in vim loses highlight in mac-osx only?

**VIM-7.4.1016 - Mac OSX:**

[image: VIM-7.4.1016 - Mac OSX]

**VIM-7.4.629 Linux:**

[image: VIM-7.4.629 Linux]

And thats how my `~/.vimrc` file look like for both:

```
" =======================================
" .vimrc file
" =======================================
"
" My default config and plugins for vim :)
" Weslley Araujo <http://github.com/weslleyaraujo>
" =======================================

" Load plugins
"
if filereadable(expand("~/vundle.vim"))
  source ~/vundle.vim
endif

" =======================================
" My default configs
" =======================================
syntax enable
set encoding=utf-8

" tab
set tabstop=2 
set shiftwidth=2
set softtabstop=2
set autoindent
set expandtab 

" interface
set wildmenu        " set vim menu
set ruler           " show cursor position
set cursorline      " hightlight for actual line
set number          " show numbers
set hlsearch        " set highlight for search
set nowrap          " set no wrap for big lines
set nobackup        " set no backup
set incsearch
set background=dark
hi link htmlLink NONE "remove underline from links in html pages

" =======================================
" Files syntax
" =======================================
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead {*.html.ejs,*.erb} set syntax=html
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead {Gemfile,Gemfile.lock,*.ru} set syntax=ruby
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.json set syntax=javascript

" =======================================
" Maps
" =======================================
nmap <c-n> :bn<CR> " map (ctrl + n) => :bn // buffer next
nmap <c-p> :bp<CR> " map (ctrl + p) => :bp // buffer prev

" =======================================
" Colorscheme
" =======================================
try
    colorscheme bubblegum-256-dark
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E185/
    echo 'Cant find colorscheme bubblegum yet!'
endtry
```

And thats the theme I am using: **https://github.com/baskerville/bubblegum**

Any ideas what can be causing it or how to fix this kind of issue?

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, but maybe you would like to try [Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim). In my opinion, it fixes a couple of things that Vim does not do very well. Although it may not be the case anyway. :-P

Comment: Try running `vim --noplugin`. And then cry when your favorite plugin turns out to be incredibly hard to debug.

Answer (score 2):

I opened an issue in the the theme repository and it turns out that there was a bug on it.

It was fixed in the last release and after updating it is working as expected for me.

As follow:
https://github.com/baskerville/bubblegum/issues/4

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Root cause for those who are interested: setting guifg, ctermfg, or any fg highlight on the CursorLine (or CursorColumn, for that matter) highlight will override the other fg highlights that would otherwise be visible.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with VIM on my Mac. Then I discovered that it was loading additional settings for Mac. I disabled these additional settings by using the following line in my `.vimrc` **right after** `set cursor line`:

```
:let macvim_skip_colorscheme=1
```

and everything was ok.